# Copy entire php page to another _blank php page

Tags: php, html, copy

I'm trying to copy the content of a preview php page with a bunch of variables to a new blank php page to print, but all I get in the blank is the code I wrote in the preview page.

I'm storing the content of preview.php into a variable to retrieve it in blank_print.php

I tried `POST`, `COOKIE`, `GET`, `SESSION` but I got nothing. I don't know if I used them correctly though.
In preview.php I get all input fields from page1.php, I set them into a table for preview (perfect so far) and, if correct, press a print button to open a new window (fails to load previous data), print it, and finish the job.

**preview.php:**

```
  $content= 'page1, content with $variables';<br>
    echo $content;
```

**blank_print.php:**

```
file_get_contents($content,'preview.php');<br>
    echo $content;
```

//also tried `echo $_POST[$content]`;

Looked in the site and found this

You can set the php.ini value allow_url_fopen to true, then you can do this in a single line using `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents():`

```
 file_put_contents($file, file_get_contents($url));
```

But I don't realy know how to use it nor if it the solution to my problem.

Thanks a lot for any help!!

Comment: in file_get_Contents(), give the content to be obtained alone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use session variables.

To start a session you have to call `session_start();` at the top of every page who will use sessions. For example:

```
<?php 
session_start();
...
```

Then you can use session variables to "transfer" variables and information between pages. For example:

page1.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = "Value";
?>
```

page2.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['test']; // Will output "Value"
?>
```

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) you can read more about sessions.

Comment: yep, sessions or cookies (session are server side stored, cookies are client side stored.)

Comment: I've already tried this way, but it keeps giving me an 'Undefined index: test in C//path...' error. It's like it doesn't get the session variable value from the previous page. I've already an active session named "session" and I used an if (isset) statment to avoid user from getting to those pages unless they are loged in. Would the problem be there? Can I start two sessions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You start one session which can include several session variables. Sounds like you haven't included `session_start();` on all of the pages. I don't think `isset()` is the problem. Use [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) to send me your code.

Comment: Genius! I was already posting the pastebin links but I gave myself another shot... and done it! as you guys suggested I created a 'body' variable to store the page data I want to send (containing html code and php variables). Then I created a new SESSION variable after the code assigning the 'body' variable value to it. It works like a charm!! Thank you very much guys!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you mean.
The best way is using $_SESSION

Store your variables in a Session before you Save or submit your form.

Toturial:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: Perfect! I was creating the SESSION variable before the variable I wanted to store. Great solution! Thanks very much man!